# Cloud Function Failing Everytime, Any Account, with default function template

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Cloud Function Failing Everytime, Any Account, with default function template. With a blank error page (as owner IAM role).

[image]

Comment: 1) Enable the Chrome debugger and check for more detailed error messages. 2) Deploy using the CLI and check for more detailed error messages.

Comment: Are you still login?

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue?